# ¿Cómo obtener la palabra más larga de un diccionario en Python?

Tags: python

No sé cómo obtener en un diccionario:

1. La palabra más larga.
2. Las 10 palabras más comunes.
3. El total de palabras distintas.

```py
d={'casa': 40, 'and': 42, 'ordenador': 32, 'pelo': 1, '2': 2, 'cosa': 2, '': 119, 'j': 1 }
```

Comment: Hola liz, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. Deberías pasarte por [tour] y [ask] para conocer un poco mejor el sitio y aprender cómo hacer buenas preguntas. Supongo que con "la palabra más larga" te refieres a la clave más larga del diccionario ¿No? ¿Qué son los valores de las claves de tu diccionario? ¿El número de apariciones de dicha palabra? Además de aclarar esto, deberías agregar lo que has intentado, aunque no funcione, para que la pregunta muestre investigación previa y no corra el riesgo de terminar cerrada. Un saludo.

Comment: Huele a tarea... que has intentado? Si no has intentado nada entonces no podremos ayudarte, la comunidad es para intentar resolver algo que ya hiciste y no funciona. No hacemos proyectos o tareas desde cero

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de que los números indiquen la cantidad de veces que aparece la palabra, puedes hacer esto:

```
d={'casa': 40, 'and': 42, 'ordenador': 32, 'pelo': 1, '2': 2, 'cosa': 2, '': 119, 'j': 1 }

k=d.keys()
word=""
gret=[]
for element in k:
    if len(element) > len(word):
        word=element

vals=sorted(d.values())[::-1]

for number in range(len(vals)):
    gret.append(list(d.keys())[list(d.values()).index(vals[number])])


cont=0
wrd=""
for words,number in d.items():
    if words != wrd:
        cont+=1
        wrd=words

print("Palabra más larga: ")   
print(word)
print("10 palabras más comunes: ")
print(gret[0:9]) 
print("Palabras distintas: ")
print(cont)
```